# heroku error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, maven, heroku

I've created a simple app that uses gradle and maven, and i'm trying to run it on heroku. The build completes successfully, but the app crashes immediately afterwards.

```
2020-05-16T01:54:59.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-05-16T01:55:03.088181+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-05-16T01:55:04.411587+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2020-05-16T01:55:04.216434+00:00 app[worker.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2020-05-16T01:55:04.331808+00:00 app[worker.1]: Error: Could not find or load main class <classname>
```

My procfile contains this:

```
worker: java -jar target/<jarname>.jar
```

Another thing I've found which could be a problem is the directory for my main class- I didn't give it a group when i created the project so it's Directory is:

src\main\Main.java

Could this be a problem?

Answer (score 2):

The error message is pretty clear... "Could not find or load main class" Apparently, none of your class files contain a `public static void main(String[] args)` method signature, so Heroku has no entry point to start your project.

The JVM needs to see a `main` method with that exact signature. `main` is just a convention that lets the JVM know where the initial entry point is to execute your code. `public` has to be there for the sake of access, and `static` allows `main` to be called without having created an instance of whatever object includes the `main` method.

Comment: my code contains the line ` public static void main(String[] args) throws LoginException {`, do I need to remove the void statement or is something else going wrong?

Comment: Sorry, void is required -- that's just a late night brainfart on my part. Look in your app's root dir and find the procfile. Edit your original question and post the contents there. We're moving on to the more obscure causes now.

Comment: added the procfile.

Comment: @MarsAtomic Any idea on this? I experience the same, even though Heroku runs perfectly locally?